# A question about Fourier Transform of a derivative

Tags: fourier-transform

The Fourier Transform (FT) of the function $x(t)$ is define by
$$
\mathcal{F}_x(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt
$$
It is well known that
$$
\mathcal{F}_{x'}(\omega)=j\omega\mathcal{F}_x(\omega)
$$
In order to verify that result, I wanted to compute the FT of
$$
y(t)=
\begin{cases}
  1 & t\in(-1,1)\\
  0 & \hbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
using the FT of
$$
x(t)=
\begin{cases}
  t & t\in(-1,1)\\
  0 & \hbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
By direct computation I got that
$$
\mathcal{F}_x(\omega)=2j\cdot\frac{\omega\cos\omega-\sin\omega}{\omega^2}
$$
Since $x'=y$ we deduce that
$$
\mathcal{F}_y(\omega)=j\omega\cdot2j\cdot\frac{\omega\cos\omega-\sin\omega}{\omega^2}=
2(\mathrm{sinc}(\omega)-\cos\omega)
$$
**My question**: By direct computation I got that $\mathcal{F}_y(\omega)=2\mathrm{sinc}(\omega)$. What is the correct result?

Comment: The function $x$ is not continuous at $-1$ and $1$ and hence is not derivable. If you want to make sense to what you did, I think you have to check the notion of Fourier transform over tempered distribution. There's is a formula for differentiating a piecewise $\mathcal C^1$ function involving distributions but I only know its french name and I cannot find it in english. It adds a corrective term to the derivation formula. But I think you can find easier examples if your goal is just to try the formula you are talking about (and you can try to show it too, maybe).

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that this is the problem. Does FT of two functions that are different in a finite number of points are identical?

Comment: Usually, FT is taken on functions defined almost everywhere, so yes in that case.

Comment: If so, $y'$ and $x$ are different at $-1$ and $1$ and still their FS is different. Does the reason is because $y'$ not defined everywhere?

Comment: by $y'$ and $x$ do you actually mean $x'$ and $y$ ? If so, here $x'$ doesn't exist. The function $x$ is differentiable almost everywhere, but the property about FT and derivatives is only about everywhere differentiable functions. You cannot say that the formula is still true by stating that $x' = y$ almost everywhere because **$x'$ doesn't exist**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are not continuous. The "well-known" equality
$$
\mathcal{F}_{x'}(\omega)=j\omega\mathcal{F}_x(\omega)
$$
is a trivial consequence of integration by parts, *when $x$ is differentiable and integrable*; this is what makes the first term in the integration by parts
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x'(t)\,e^{-i\omega t}\,dt=x(t)\,e^{-i\omega t}\bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty+\frac1{i\omega}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)\,e^{-i\omega t}\,dt
$$
vanish. The problem you have is that Barrow's rule
$$
\int_a^b f'=f(b)-f (a)
$$
requires $f$ to be differentiable everywhere. For instance consider your $x$ and you have
$$
\int_{-2}^2 x'(t)\,dt=2\ne 0= x(2)-x(-2).
$$

Comment: Thanks Martin. Does FT of two functions that are different in a finite number of points are identical ?

Comment: @boaz No, counter-example : the constant zero function and the Dirac delta function.

Comment: @boaz: with the definition as used in your question, yes. The Riemann/Lebesgue integral does not see finite sets. If you extend from functions to measures, as mentioned by Abezhiko, then the Dirac delta gives you an example of a measure that differs from the zero measure at a single point, and the transforms are different.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your answer